# Biblatex: entrytype for authors and indirection

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to somehow support multiple writings for names (romaji, kanji, hanzi, furigana, etc) of authors. Now this is not supported, and the experimental `vform` interface never made it into biblatex.

I came up with the idea to define a new entry type for authors, and reference these authors in books (some similar to related).

Here is a minimal version of the `multiscript.dtx`:

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{person}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  kanji,
  furi,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
   romaji,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[person]{
   kanji,
   furi,
   romaji,
}
```

and a little `mwe.bib`:

```
@person{n1,
   kanji = {kanji},
  furi  = {furi},
  romaji = "First Second",
}
@book{b1,
  author = {n1},
  title  = {A great book},
}
```

With these in hand the following `mwe.tex` compiles:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=multiscript,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{romaji}{%
  \printnames{romaji}%
}
\newbibmacro*{kanji}{%
  [\printfield{kanji}]}
\newbibmacro*{furi}{%
  (\printfield{furi})}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{person}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{romaji}%
  \addspace
  \usebibmacro{furi}%
  \addspace
  \usebibmacro{kanji}%
  \addspace
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
The author First Second \cite{n1} wrote book \cite{b1}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now, what I would like to achieve is something that when the book is printed, there is a loop over the lastnames (which are just links to other entries), and then using

```
\entrydata{<lastname>}{%
  \printnames{romaji} ....
```

so that the linked entry is used to print the names.

I tried

```
\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily[1]{%
  \message{[mkbibnamefamily] key = #1 ^^J}
  \entrydata{#1}{%
     \printnames{romaji} (\printfield{kanji}, \printfield{furi})}}
```

but that didn't work, no last name and no field whatsoever displayed. Also, the function would be used also for listing references to names (`\cite{n1}`, which is also useful in the current context).

Any suggestion how to implement this indirection?

Thanks

Norbert

Comment: I like your idea to export person infos. I don't have currently the time to test but imho in your current setup it is difficult to handle more than one author and also it could get difficult if not every author has a @person entry. Did you saw https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416 which added extended possibilities to define author names? Imho it would be a good idea to ask there for a "crossref={key}" option

Comment: Thanks, yes I have seen that feature request. I guess one could check whether there is an entry and if not treat it as a normal name instead of a reference. Or one adds \refname{n1} in the author, would also be fine.

Comment: I'll think about this too . There are many difficulties with implenting multiscript support and I've also thought about using something like the related entries model.

Comment: Hi Phil, that would be great - but do you have a suggestion how to manage this for the above single case? Is it possible to make `mkbibnamefamily` only act on some entry types?

Comment: There is now a "multiscript" branch of biblatex (the "experimental" folder on Sourceforge). It is version 4.0 and requires biber 4.0. It should do what you want and if you can get some MWE together of what you ideally want to do, I can try to make an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the recursion into `\mkbibnamefamily` via `\printnames` when the argument is not a reference to another entry otherwise the `\entrydata` call will have nothing useful in it:

```
\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily[1]{%
  \message{[mkbibnamefamily] key = #1 ^^J}%
  \ifentryinbib{#1}%
    {\entrydata{#1}{%
       \printnames{romaji} (\printfield{kanji}, \printfield{furi})}}
    {#1}}
```

Comment: Thanks indeed! The `\ifentryinbib` was what I was searching for. Great.