# Localized author's names?

Tags: biblatex

I have a few bibliography entries somewhat like this:

> Plato. Hippias Minor. In: Platonis Opera. Oxford: Clarendon Press, 1903. v. 3.

The citation norms I have to use right now require that I write Plato's name in Portuguese (Platão). But I really don't want to change all my entries that use the name "Plato" to "Platão". So for now I'm adding different entries, some with the names in Portuguese and some with the names in Latin/English. That doesn't seem like a great solution. I thought about using a `\bibstring{plato}`, so I'd have a single entry that would adapt to each language, but then I'd have to add the `NewBibliographyString` to each of my `tex` files, which doesn't seem very nice either.

Can anyone think of a better option?

Comment: This is coming up more often as a question. There are plans for a "multiscript" functionality in biblatex for exactly this purpose but the  PoC I did of this a few years ago turned out to complicate the internals too much and we're currently re-thinking it. In the interim, you might look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318231/biblatex-entrytype-for-authors-and-indirection

Comment: You can define the strings in a configuration or language file and/or a single `.tex` file. You don't need to repeat them in each document.

Comment: @PLK Interesting, I'll look forward to that feature. Thanks!

Comment: @cfr Good point, I guess that seems like the best/simplest option for now.

Comment: @cfr Do you want to write an answer? You could also mention `@string` in the `.bib` file, then there is one central place to change the name.